# How can I delete a write only protected folder

Tags: command-line

I cannot delete a folder as it says write only protected.Though I am using from root It says that I am not a root user.
As I am new in using Ubuntu. Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Could you post the command you are using? Did you try with `sudo`?

Comment: What are the exact steps and the output of `ls -l /directory`, `lsattr /directory` and `mount`

Answer (score 27):

From the terminal you can run:

```
sudo rm -r /my/locked/directory
```

as the instruction will prompt any warning message during the execution and you will be able to check what are you deleting. Otherwise, **if you have checked the warning and are completely sure of files and subfolders contained**, you can run:

```
sudo rm -rf /my/locked/directory
```

This will remove recursively (`-r`) your folder, subfolders and any contents without prompt any warning (`-f`) .

---

If you receive the message: `rm: cannot remove '/my/locked/directory': operation not permitted`, then make sure directory (or file) is not protected using extended file system `i` attribute.

A file/folder with the `i` attribute cannot be modified, it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file. Only root can add or remove `i` attribute.

Use `lsattr` command to verify that file/folder is not write protected using extended `i` attribute - output should be:

```
----i-------- /my/locked/directory
```

To remove the `i` attribute you can run:

```
sudo chattr -i /my/locked/directory
```

then check again with `lsattr`. The `i` should have been removed. If removed run the `sudo rm -r` instructions above.

Comment: In the `rm` statement I would also add the `-v` option to see which folders/files have been deleted.

Comment: Why do you want to use the -r?!?!

Comment: to recursive remove the entire directory and all its contents, including subdirectories

Comment: I know, but why would you want to do this on a directory which you know nothing about?

Comment: Also, the filesystem might be mounted read-only, or the medium might not support write operations in the first place (e.g. a CD-ROM or a write-protected flash drive).

Comment: @Braiam you are right. I thought at a general case of folder with subfolder. Running the command above would not change the result even if the folder is empty... But anyway - I will update my answer accordingly to be more specific.

Comment: It worked for swap files too. Only: "rm -r /my/locked/directory" didn't delete the directory; it prompted: "Permission denied". Including sudo, it deleted everything with the directory.